# Parsing wikiText with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, mediawiki, wikitext

Given a wikiText string such as:

```
{{ValueDescription
    |key=highway
    |value=secondary
    |image=Image:Meyenburg-L134.jpg
    |description=A highway linking large towns.
    |onNode=no
    |onWay=yes
    |onArea=no
    |combination=
    * {{Tag|name}}
    * {{Tag|ref}}
    |implies=
    * {{Tag|motorcar||yes}}
    }}
```

I'd like to parse templates `ValueDescription` and `Tag` in Java/Groovy.
I tried with with regex `/\{\{\s*Tag(.+)\}\}/` and it's fine (it returns `|name` `|ref` and `|motorcar||yes`), but 
`/\{\{\s*ValueDescription(.+)\}\}/` doesn't work (it should return all the text above).

The expected output

Is there a way to skip nested templates in the regex?

Ideally I would rather use a simple **wikiText 2 xml** tool, but I couldn't find anything like that.

Thanks!
Mulone

Comment: Can you please provide some sample outputs you are expecting from above input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your regex pattern using `Pattern.DOTALL` option like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{\\s*ValueDescription(.+)\\}\\}", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

#### Sample Code:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\{\\{\\s*ValueDescription(.+)\\}\\}",Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
while (m.find())
   System.out.println("Matched: [" + m.group(1) + ']');
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Matched: [
|key=highway
|value=secondary
|image=Image:Meyenburg-L134.jpg
|description=A highway linking large towns.
|onNode=no
|onWay=yes
|onArea=no
|combination=
* {{Tag|name}}
* {{Tag|ref}}
|implies=
* {{Tag|motorcar||yes}}
]
```

#### Update

Assuming closing `}}` appears on a separate line for `{{ValueDescription` following pattern will work to capture multiple `ValueDescription`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{\\s*ValueDescription(.+?)\n\\}\\}", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: this works but if there's another '''{{ValueDescription''' block it won't stop.

Comment: @Mulone: Assuming closing `}}` appears on a separate line for `{{ValueDescription` following pattern will work to capture multiple `ValueDescription`: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{\\s*ValueDescription(.+?)\n\\}\\}", Pattern.DOTALL);`

Comment: I don't think that that assumption is valid when reading wikitext. Is there a way to make it robust?

Comment: @Mulone: Regular expressions do have limitations here, you need to have some type of pattern to match. Closing `}}` must be either on a separate line or be followed by some other character that we can use in the pattern above. For validating/matching a non-regular text you will eventually need a parser utility or will need to write your own parser.

Answer (score 4):

Arbitrarily nested tags won't work since that's makes the grammar [non-regular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).  You need something capable of dealing with a context-free grammar.  [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) is a fine option.